# Embedded `PDF` file not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I placed my test `pdf` file in `dropbox` and got the public link :

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6257603/pdfs/pdf01.pdf
```

I would like to show this (embed) to my html page. (i would like to create a tree structured multiple links to load the uploaded `pdf` to show to user)

i got a answer saying that, `pdf` can embedable in `html` file here :

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?152923-PDF-within-a-DIV

but i couln't see any output. here is my try:

```css
div {
    border : 1px solid red;
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <object data="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6257603/pdfs/pdf01.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the problem? your snippet is showing fine for me

Comment: also display fine for me . please check on your side.

Comment: are you running noscript or adblock or some other object blocker (e.g. browser config)?

Comment: I just look in to `chrome` may be i need to test with other browsers.

Comment: any one, this is bad question, is it possible to control the `pdf` content by js script. (ex: can i copy and paste the content from pdf to another div, using js/jquery'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change code to this :

```
<div>
 <object data="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6257603/pdfs/pdf01.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
   <embed src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6257603/pdfs/pdf01.pdf" type="application/pdf">
 </object>
</div>
```